# Edit text view issue

Tags: android

Hi friends
    I have an editable text box with a default value like to display to the user like "entername". If the user touches the edit box, I want to clear the value of edittext box and show the virtual keypad to the user, and if the user presses the enter key, only in the edit text box, I have to start another activity. How do I do this?

Hi in android:hint at the type of key pressing only it clear value I want to on touch in edit text box clear value and show virtual keypad to user. How do I do this?

Thanks

Comment: what  are you trying 2 ask??????Please be clear........
I think you are in need of hint attribute. android:hint="your hint....."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What?

I really don't understand what you're asking, but it seems like you might be trying to do a `hint`? Rather than setting an onTouchEvent listener, add a `android:hint="What to do"` attribute to your EditText.

Answer (score 0):

U use the following code
EditText EditTextName=findViewById(R.id.EditText01);

```
((InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).showSoftInput(EditTextName), 0);
```

use this code in ontouchListener of EditText

Answer (score 0):

Mohan if I am correct you have two questions here

1. How to display a hint in an edit box
2. How get some data from a web service

For the first question you can use android:hint="Enter Name"

For the second one you need to give us more info on what you are trying to do